# Is the Location Header Ignored for Specific HTTP Response Codes?

Tags: http, redirect, http-headers, httpresponse

**Related Questions:**

- [For Which Redirection Responses are Location Headers Mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194988/for-which-3xx-http-codes-is-the-location-header-mandatory)
- [Is it Possible to Send a 401 Unauthorized and Redirect with a Location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775593/is-it-possible-to-send-a-401-unauthorized-and-redirect-with-a-location)

While trying to figure out how to send error responses for users in PHP, I came across these interesting questions above. In one of the answers to the 2nd question listed above, it was mentioned that the Location headers are ignored for responses other than redirects. I was looking at the [HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.1) and from what I have looked at, there is no mention of ignoring any `Location` headers within the spec.

So, is the `Location` header within an HTTP response actually ignored for response codes that are not classified as redirects (3XX)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are status codes where Location is relevant as well, such as 201 Created. It varies on status code, not status code class.