# In Layman's Terms, What Purpose Does the Warning Header Field in HTTP/1.1 Serve?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, client-server, semantics

**Related Questions:**

- [`HTTP 403` Response vs `HTTP 401` Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)
- [Is it Possible to Send an `HTTP 401` and `HTTP 302` Redirect with a Location Header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775593/is-it-possible-to-send-a-401-unauthorized-and-redirect-with-a-location)

**Background:**

I'm developing a PHP web application that will redirect clients to custom error pages based on the semantic errors encountered. The specific one related to my question is which error to serve when a client that is logged out attempts to access a resource that is protected.

I've read people doing the following:

- Just use the PHP function `header()` to redirect using a standard `HTTP 302` to your error page
- Have a PHP script call a custom function that checks the permissions of the client and serves the appropriate error page as an included template
- Utilize the existing Basic or Digest authentication built into HTTP.

**The Dilemma**

Since I'm using a PHP form-based methodology with sessions to authenticate users, and the HTTP 1.1 spec calls for a mandatory [`WWW-Authenticate` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-10.4.2), I don't want to send a `HTTP 401` response back ( even though it looks the most attractive to just send and deviate from spec ).

**Question**

I noticed an optional [`Warning Header`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-14.46) under general headers that perhaps I could use to send also with my request. Can I use the warning header to show to a client that my particular response is semantically different than an assumed generic response?