# Node Express - redirect to login view

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to configure my express application to redirect to a login page based on some logic. I have the following:

```
  app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.session.accessToken){
      //do something here
    }
    next();
  });
```

I have a login.html file located in the root of the directory my application is being served from, I am just unsure what I need to call on the `res` object e.g. `redirect`, `send`

Also, I know the above will actually cause an infinite loop.

What's the correct approach here?

Comment: Are you trying to password protect _only_ `/`, or the entire site except the login page?

Comment: entire site except for login. So I guess  could redirect to say '/login' and set up a route handler for a GET to '/login', but I just need to know how I serve up the login.html page

Comment: Did you try **res.redirect("/your/url/here")**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to be careful of your handler order, what you want (if you *really* want to do this on your own and not use something like [Passport](http://passportjs.org/)) is something like (the somewhat skeleton);

```
app.use('/login', function(req, res) {   // Allows access to login page
    res.send('displaying login page');   // before access token check
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {       // Catches access to all other pages
    if(!req.session.accessToken) {       // requiring a valid access token
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

// the rest of your routes go here, they should not be called unless authenticated
```

Comment: Ok thanks and what about sending of the actual login.html? Could I do something like res.send(login.html)?

Comment: @mindparse If you're using express 4.8.0 or later, the easiest is probably to use `res.sendFile('login.html')`

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious answer is to simply call `res.redirect('/login.html')`, but that would return a `301` (moved permanently) code to the browser. A more semantically correct solution might be to return a `401` (unauthorized) and render the `login.html` file to the response.

See [Is it possible to send a 401 Unauthorized AND redirect (with a Location)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775593/is-it-possible-to-send-a-401-unauthorized-and-redirect-with-a-location)

So a solution might look something like this:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.session.accessToken)
    res.status(401).sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/login.html'));
  else
    next()
});
```